# BSON Document to POJO with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

We are using Morphia to read/write POJOs from/into MongoDB with Java.
This works very well.

Now, for a unit test, I have BSON document (a dump of 1 document from my MongoDB) in a textfile and want to convert it into a POJO.

I want to use Morphia for this conversion, but I cannot see how.

Any pointers are appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, dbName);
ClassType classFieldName = morphia.fromDBObject(datastore, ClassType.class, BsonDocument( instance of DBObject));
```